# Glassfish, railo and coldbox - messed up links?

Tags: coldfusion, glassfish, railo, coldbox

I am new to ColdFusion and ColdBox (and programming). I tried to setup ColdBox but some of the links in the sample applications are broken.

My configuration is a GlassFish v3 installation with the current Railo OSS. I access my site through Apache 2.2.14.

So instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8080/railo/` I access my environment trough `http://railo/`.

In Railo I have a webroot mapping `/` to `C:/webapps/myproject/`.

I have copied the current ColdBox 3M4 to `C:/webapps/myproject/coldbox`. I can access the dashboard through `http://railo/coldbox/dashboard/index.cfm` and have access to all options.

My problems start the moment I try to open the sample gallery:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report
message
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
it from fulfilling this request.
exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\webapps\viss-dev\coldbox\samples
(Zugriff verweigert)
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
available in the GlassFish v3 logs.
GlassFish v3
```

OK, no problem, just enter the link directly: `http://railo/coldbox/samples/index.cfm`.

The site looks plain, who cares - BUT all local links look like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/coldbox/samples/applications/helloworld/index.cfm` (`railo` is replaced with `127.0.0.1:8080`).

Looks like trouble. To make my confusion perfect: when I try to access the login app: `http://railo/coldbox/samples/applications/sampleloginapp/index.cfm` and hit the submit button, I am redirected to this address: `http://railo/railo/coldbox/samples/applications/sampleloginapp/index.cfm`.

I believe that this is not really ColdBox-related, but it manifests itself when I try to use ColdBox, so here I am.

P.S.: amazon.de takes too long to ship the ColdBox book :(

Comment: Have you tried to fix the "access denied" error you get? Clearly the CF service does not have access to the ColdBox sample directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have given up on glassfish and i am now struggling with tomcat :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to ColdFusion (and programming in general), I would recommend developing against Adobe ColdFusion. The Developer Edition of ColdFusion is free and available from Adobe.com. You won't need to mess around or configure GlassFish since Adobe ColdFusion comes with a baked-in pre-configured Tomcat, providing both servlet engine and web server.

Just install the 'Stand-alone' version of ColdFusion Developer Edition, copy the ColdBox files into the webroot and in less than 15 minutes you be up and running.

You should also check out ColdFusion Builder which is currently available in beta from  http://labs.adobe.com. It has full language support and integrated help content for learning the ins-outs of the language.

As far as the ColdBox book goes, it's available as an eBook if you really can't wait. ;-)

DISCLAIMER: I spend about 50% of my waking life devoted to making ColdFusion better as the CF Product Manager at Adobe. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion, The good people at Vivotech have developed a couple of different installers for both Windows/IIS7 and various flavours of Linux for both Railo and Open BlueDragon. The setup installs Tomcat, Railo/Open Blue Dragon and the necessary connectors to the web server. Here's the link: http://www.viviotech.net/company/installers.cfm

I think you'll find using the installers to be a lot easier than working through it yourself. If you want to go that route, Adobe and various bloggers have instructions on how to do it. Matt Woodward has a very good blog posting on it: see [MattWoodward.com](http://www.mattwoodward.com/blog/index.cfm?event=showEntry&entryId=60F08421-5F0A-41C9-940B3681A3D09D99), He also has a presentation on this, you can see it [here](http://www.mattwoodward.com/blog/index.cfm?event=showEntriesByCategory&categoryId=8CB6A1F5-0CBD-4ED9-A2D6E36C8BCF874F&categoryName=Tomcat).

hth,

larry